# In R, what is the difference between predict() function and model$predicted value?

Tags: r, random-forest

If I apply a random forest model to a training set in R,

```
forest = randomForest(y ~ ., data = dat)
pred1 = predict(forest, newdata = dat)
pred2 = forest$predicted
```

the second row and third row are the same model applied to the same dataset, but why do they give out different values?

`pred1` was used to compare with the true response values and calculate RMSE for the training set; while `pred2` was used to compare with the true response values and calculate RMSE for the testing set (out-of-bagging error)?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `predict(forest, newdata=training_data)` with random forests. That will give a distorted picture of the model's accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a typo in your second line. Using a reproducible example and with "forect" in the second line changed to "forest", I appear to have the same outputs from your second and third line.

```
forest = randomForest(vs~., data = mtcars)
predict(forest, data = mtcars)
forest$predicted
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I use `predict(forest, newdata = mtcars)` instead of `predict(forest, data = mtcars)`, the output values are different, why is it the case?

Comment: From the predict help file: "Most prediction methods which are similar to those for linear models have an argument newdata specifying the first place to look for explanatory variables to be used for prediction. Some considerable attempts are made to match up the columns in newdata to those used for fitting, for example that they are of comparable types and that any factors have the same level set in the same order (or can be transformed to be so)."

Comment: Apparently, newdata and data are different arguments for the predict function and don't have the same effect on behavior

Answer (score 0):

`$predicted` is a numeric vector containing predictions for the train dataset (the one that's been passed to `randomForest()`)

`predict()` is a method that allows you to use a model (such as a `randomForest` model) to create fitted values for absolutely any input that fits the expected schema (which does not have to be the test set)